# Using "expression" to create list of labels with some italics, using values from a dataframe

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm trying to create a list of labels that contain italics. I can do it with "expression" like this, and when I put them on a plot (by adding a legend as an example, but I'll use them different ways), it all works nicely.

```
sp.names=c(expression(paste("species ",italic("one")," sp.")),
           expression(paste("species ",italic("two")," sp.")))
plot(1:10)
legend("topleft",legend=sp.names)
```

[image]

But instead of specifying the words in the label directly in the code, I want to call them from cells in a dataframe (because there are a lot of them and they change depending on my underlying data). But when I try and specify which dataframe cell I want, it doesn't print the labels correctly (see below). Perhaps there is a different way for me to call the cell that I want that the "expression" function will recognise?

```
df=data.frame(V1=c("species","species","species"),V2=c("one","two","three"))
sp.names=c(expression(paste(df$V1[1],italic(df$V2[1])," sp.")),
           expression(paste(df$V1[2],italic(df$V2[2])," sp.")))
plot(1:10)
legend("topleft",legend=sp.names)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `substitute`, it substitutes variables in expressions.

```
sp.names=c(substitute(V1 ~ italic(V2) ~ "sp.", df[1,]),
           substitute(V1 ~ italic(V2) ~ "sp.", df[2,]))
```

I also removed the unneeded `paste` (which has a different meaning within plotmath) and replaced it with `~` for increased readability.

Comment: Thanks. Although I had trouble because "sp.names" was coming out as a list with the code above rather than a vector (and so it wasn't working). I'm sure there are better ways to fix it, but I found adding an empty expression at the end made it work: "sp.names<-c(substitute(V1 ~ italic(V2) ~ "sp.", df[1,]), substitute(V1 ~ italic(V2) ~ "sp.", df[2,]), expression())"

Comment: Why is it being a list an issue? What was not working? If you need an expression vector, the canonical way is `as.vector(sp.names, mode = "expression")`.

Comment: Thanks @Roland, yes  - the formula was being printed on the graph rather than the actual label (same as the original problem). Thanks for the code for the expression vector.

Answer (score 1):

Give `bquote` a shot.

```
sp.names <- c(bquote(.(df$V1[1])~italic(.(df$V2[1]))~" sp."),
              bquote(.(df$V1[2])~italic(.(df$V2[2]))~" sp."))

plot(1:10)
legend("topleft", legend=sp.names)
```